# xbp24c don't hear anything from AT86RF233

Tags: zigbee

I'm using an digi XBPC24CZ7WIT-004-revF to listen to an AT86RF233 ( http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/AT86RF233 ) but I don't succeed.

I tried with a CC2531 ( http://www.ti.com/tool/CC2531EMK ) in place of the xbp24C and it works "out of the box". Here's a screenshot of some packets.

[image]

Using xctu, I set panId to 0xFFFF and scan channels to 1 ( I know these parameters are correct, I can see them in CC2531 GUI ).

I suspect a misconfiguration (I hope it's not an incompatibility).

What else should I do or look out?

Regards
Julien

Comment: You definitely think it's a xbp24C software problem?

Comment: What do you mean? The XBP is connected to terminal/PC through a ftdi. I suspect a misconfiguration (I hope it's not an incompatibility).

Comment: What is the exact part number of the XBP24C?

Comment: XBPC24CZ7WIT-004-revF

Comment: Have you attempted making the CC2531 and XBPC24CZ7WIT-004 talk?

Comment: @SolveEtCoagula07 : Just tried it, XBP is talking but is not eared by CC2531

Comment: @Julien I found this, maybe it will help? https://www.digi.com/support/forum/2858/xbee-pro-coordinator-%26-cc2531-router-connection-problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you fill in the 802.15.4 frame format correctly?

You need to fill the `PHR` and `PSDU` for each packet, and make sure you're in `PLL_ON` state before begin the transmit command in AT86RF233 (either writing register 0x02 address with 0x02 value, or assert `slp_tr` to high).